# What does "_('foo')" mean in Python?

Tags: python

I was looking at some python code and saw this:

```
class ActionListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('action')
```

Is `_('action')` method of a tuple? Is that a coding "convention"?

Sorry if this a duplicate, but it hard to search for `_()` in SO or web search engines.

Comment: Here, `_` is a function, probably returning a translation for 'action'.

Comment: Where is the function defined? Is it built in?

Comment: @user2357112 Uhhh, I'm pretty sure the `_` here is a shorthand for a "translate this text" function.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Yes, and that's in the duplicate.

Comment: Eh, I guess it's in *one* of the answers. It's not what the *question* is about though. Not a fan of the dupe, but whatever.

Comment: If you're using Django, as I suppose, have a look at [internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/) for more info.

Comment: "Is it a function or a variable?" There is no meaningful difference between functions and values in Python.

Comment: "Is it a function or a variable?" - functions are stored in variables like any other.

Comment: You can probably see it in the list of imports at the top of your file. One of them will end with `as _`.

Comment: @Ry- Yep there is this at the top of the file `from django.utils.translation import pgettext_lazy, ugettext_lazy as _`. Thanks