# Django Models - Field Syntax

Tags: python, django, model

Quick question regarding some syntax when creating django models. If you take a look at the example models.py file below, you'll see that each of the four fields contain a repeat of the field name as a string in parentheses preceded my an underscore. I assume this is some kind of visual representation for when this is encountered in a form, but that seems to happen automatically in admin with out the _('field name').

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Is this code someone else wrote and you are now maintaining?

Comment: No, it's from a tutorial I stumbled upon pertaining to extending the django user model.

Comment: The `_(string)` is not related to Django.  I personally find using goofy stuff like that very un-useful in code.  I asked about that sort of thing once here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898415/what-does-foo-mean-in-python and got an ear full.

Comment: Thank you. I will read into those answers.

Comment: In my question the answer turned out to be that at the top of the python file there was this `from django.utils.translation import pgettext_lazy, ugettext_lazy as _`. Maybe I was even following the same tutorial you are look at :-)))

Comment: Yup, here is what I am seeing above in the imports: "from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _"

Comment: Glad I wasn't the only one confused by that `_` nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the built-in field types inherit from the [Field class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field). If you look at the [`__init__()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L133) call for that class, you'll see that the first parameter in the function is the `verbose_name` parameter. So that tells us what these strings map to.

The `_('some text')` construct is a fairly prevalent syntax for doing *internationalization* (also known as **i18n**). I've seen this syntax in other languages like PHP. This allows the verbose name to be rendered in various languages when the code is translated. As you note in the comments above, the function `ugettext_lazy` is imported as the alias `_`. This allows programmers (all of whom are lazy), to type `_('some text')` instead of `ugettext_lazy('some text')` in **every** location where text needs to be translated. Since there could be hundreds (or thousands) of hard coded strings in an application, it saves the programmer lots of time in the long run.

It's an ugly hack, but it gets the job done. I dislike it particularly in Python since it overrides the sometimes useful `_` name, which often gets used as a placeholder variable name when you want to throw a value away.